# should i need to create mysql accounts for all the user who register on my website or create 1 mysql user and pass cretitials to all users

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, account

i am really confused should i need to create  seprate mysql accounts for every user who register on my website or just create 1 mysql user to query database for all users somehow i am very confused

if i create 1 mysql user for all users on my site when the number of users would grow it could lead to problem because many user may be querying at the same time which will create multiple CRUD  operations which will lead to many problems and can crash database.

i am really confused i some how dont feel its right to allow all my users on website to have mysql account of their own on database . i feel this could some how create a security threat or may be mysql has limit on number of users which can be created i really dont what i am thinking is right or not

should i create a single mysql user to let all my website users to query database to get their respective data and create a database n store all users information in one database n user relationships to connect each other website user

Answer (score 9):

You only create MySQL accounts for things that directly access MySQL. Users of a website are not accessing MySQL. They're accessing a PHP script which accesses MySQL on their behalf.

The **ONLY** time you'd create per-user accounts is if you were turning your server into a general hosting platform, and each user would be running their own databases within MySQL.

Answer (score 8):

To expand the answer from @Marc B:

I usually set up 3 user accounts for each XAMP project:

1. **project-developer**
   has full access to everything, including CREATE/GRANT. Can create tables and maintain the db.
2. **project-webuser** has SELECT access to most things, UPDATE/INSERT access only to those tables directly needed by general web users.
3. **project-webadmin** has UPDATE/INSERT access to tables needed to maintain project data.  There is usually a separate Admin web page for owners/managers to maintain the web site.